# How can I use regex in Ruby to split a string into an array of the words it contains?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern that will split a string into an array of words based on many different patterns and conventions. The rules are as follows:

1. It must split the string on all dashes, spaces, underscores, and periods.
2. When multiple of the aforementioned characters show up together, it must only split once (so 'the--.quick' must split to ['the', 'quick'] and not ['the', '', '', 'quick'] )
3. It must split the string on new capital letters, while keeping that letter with its corresponding word ('theQuickBrown' splits to ['the', 'quick', 'brown']
4. It must group multiple uppercase letters in a row together ('LETS_GO' must split to ['lets', 'go'], not ['l', 'e', 't', 's', 'g', 'o'])
5. It must use only lowercase letters in the split array.

If it is working properly, the following should be true

```
"theQuick--brown_fox JumpsOver___the.lazy  DOG".split_words == 
["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]
```

So far, I have been able to get almost there, with the only issue being that it splits on every capital, so "DOG".split_words is ["d", "o", "g"] and not ["dog"]

I also use a combination of regex and maps/filters on the split array to get to the solution, bonus points if you can tell me how to get rid of that and use only regex.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class String
  def split_words 
    split(/[_,\-, ,.]|(?=[A-Z]+)/).
    map(&:downcase).
    reject(&:empty?)
  end 
end
```

Which when called on the string from the test above returns:

```
["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "d", "o", "g"]
```

How can I update this method to meet all of the above specs?

Comment: Now you have two problems. (In case you're unfamiliar: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: You split on capital letters to break up `theQuick`, but this breaks up `DOG` .. in order to solve this, you need to determine the formal rules for this situation.

Comment: @maxpleaner what do you mean by 'formal rules'?

Comment: [`s.scan(/\p{Lu}{2,}|\p{L}\p{Ll}*/).map(&:downcase)`](https://ideone.com/scFHJ7). Supports Unicode.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? At least one other is still working on an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not gonna pretend I have a clue how that works but it does. Awesome!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I never thought about that before. I always just marked an answer when it worked. But I'm definitely going keep that in mind from now on. Where do you see if someone is working on an answer?

Comment: @JoshHadik I explained my approach in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50648815/3832970) since it proved helpful.

Comment: You cannot determine if anyone is working on an answer, but that's irrelevant to my point. When I said, "Why the rush to select an answer?", I meant precisely that. There's no rush. Not only is it discourteous to those still working on answers (imo), but quick-draw selections may discourage other, potentially superior solutions, or even keep an incorrect answer from being exposed as such. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before awarding the greenie.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah I just never thought of it in terms of rep or the best solve, it was just like 'oh did that work?' cool, I'll checkmark it. But now that you explain that makes a lot of sense. I'll change my ways!

Comment: You may have some unexpected results with your requirements. For example `"An iPhone costs about $500.00"` becomes `["an", "i", "phone", "costs", "about", "$500", "00"]`.

Comment: Note that characters in a regex character class are not separated by commas. `[_,\-, ,.]` is the same as `[_,\- .]`, so I think you want `[_\- .]`. You don't need to escape the hyphen if you put it at one end (e.g., `[_ .-]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a *matching* approach to extract chunks of 2 or more uppercase letters or a letter followed only with 0+ lowercase letters:

```
s.scan(/\p{Lu}{2,}|\p{L}\p{Ll}*/).map(&:downcase)
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/scFHJ7) and the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/U134RUjsOA).

The regex matches:

- `\p{Lu}{2,}` - 2 or more uppercase letters
- `|` - or
- `\p{L}` - any letter
- `\p{Ll}*` - 0 or more lowercase letters.

With `map(&:downcase)`, the items you get with `.scan()` are turned to lower case.

Comment: Wow thanks. Yeah this is a good solution. Love the idea of using matching to find the words rather than matching to find the characters to split on. Feels a lot more organic but for some reason the thought never crossed my mind. Changing this to the accepted answer for that reason!

Comment: @JoshHadik Ok, just do not change your mind too often. No one likes to see a -15 rep next day when the accepted mark changes place. I only posted this since you mentioned it is working for you.

Comment: yeah I never understood how that all works before today. But now that I do I will be a lot more thoughtful about choosing answers.

Comment: This strips out all characters other than letters. Besides  dashes, spaces, underscores, and periods, which are to be split upon and removed, you are removing other characters that may be present, such as digits, punctuation (e.g., commas and question marks), symbols for currencies, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

You can slightly change the regex so it doesn't split on every capital, but every sequence of letters that starts with a capital. This just involves putting a `[a-z]+` after the `[A-Z]+`

```
string = "theQuick--brown_fox JumpsOver___the.lazy  DOG"
regex = /[_,\-, ,.]|(?=[A-Z]+[a-z]+)/
string.split(regex).reject(&:empty?)
# => ["the", "Quick", "brown", "fox", "Jumps", "Over", "the", "lazy", "DOG"]
```

Comment: max, a couple of small problems: a typo (the final right paren in `regex`) and a small problem with `regex`: `[_,\-, ,.]` is the same as `[_,\- .], which incorrectly includes a comma. (The latter warrants a head-slap.)

Comment: That is a lot of commas to be sure. Looks more like an `Array` declaration than a regex character set

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland I fixed the typo. THe `[_,\-, ,.]` part I copied from the original, feel free to edit my answer to change it.

Answer (score 2):

```
r = /
    [- _.]+      # match one or more combinations of dashes, spaces,
                 # underscores and periods
    |            # or
    (?<=\p{Ll})  # match a lower case letter in a positive lookbehind
    (?=\p{Lu})   # match an upper case letter in a positive lookahead
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "theQuick--brown_dog, JumpsOver___the.--lazy   FOX for $5"

str.split(r).map(&:downcase)
  #=> ["the", "quick", "brown", "dog,", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy",
       "fox", "for", "$5"]
```

If the string is to be broken on spaces and all punctuation characters, replace `[- _.]+` with `[ [:punct:]]+`. Search for `"[[:punct:]]"` at [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) for the reference.